# DataTable Modified row count reverting to 0 after adapter fill

Tags: c#, ado.net, datatable

Apologies if this is a daft error - but have been struggling a few weeks with this and I am no further on.

The problem is - my update call from a DT based DS to an SQL Db is only inserting nerw records, not updating modifed ones.

I have a datasource (httpWebRequested html table) which I call periodically and update a DataTable belonging to a DataSet with it. Initially I parsed it all into a second DataTable and merged it with my DataSet table - but this wasnt working, so currently I have one DataTable only and either insert new rows into table or update existing values by iterating through the source and adding a row at a time to an array - checking for existance of current row, and either updating or inserting ([Session ID] is a PK, and Data[0] is corresponding unique value):-

```
                foreach (var row in rows.Skip(1))
            {
                //create new list collection
                var data = new List<string>();
                //interate through rows
                foreach (var column in row.Descendants("td"))
                {
                    //add data to list from Table
                    data.Add(column.InnerText);
                }
                    string strSelect = "[Session ID] = '"+ data[0] +"'";
                    DataRow[] myRow = dt.Select(strSelect);
                    if (myRow.Length == 1)
                    {
                        if (myRow[0][2].ToString() != data[2].ToString())
                        {
                            myRow[0][2] = data[2];
                        }
                        if (myRow[0][3].ToString() != data[3].ToString())
                        {
                            myRow[0][3] = data[3];
                        }
                        if (myRow[0][4].ToString() != data[4].ToString())
                        {
                            myRow[0][4] = data[4];
                        }
                        if (myRow[0][5].ToString() != data[5].ToString())
                        {
                            myRow[0][5] = data[5];
                        }
                        if (myRow[0][7].ToString() != data[7].ToString())
                        {
                            myRow[0][7] = data[7];
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add(data.ToArray());
                    }
```

I put a bit on the end also which counts the Added and Modified:-

```
            int modified= 0;
            int added = 0;
            foreach (DataRow dr in pca.chatDataSetG.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                if (dr.RowState == DataRowState.Modified)
                {
                    modified++;
                }
                if (dr.RowState == DataRowState.Added)
                {
                    added++;
                }
            }
```

At this point - the counts are fine - modified pick up the rows where attributes have changed and added is correct.

When I call my update Db method - things start to go wrong:-

```
    public static void updateSqlTable()
    {

        string connectionString = "Connection String here";
        string qry = @"select * from chatData";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, conn);
            SqlCommandBuilder sb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
            log.Info("Building Queries...");
            da.UpdateCommand = sb.GetUpdateCommand();
            da.InsertCommand = sb.GetInsertCommand();
            da.DeleteCommand = sb.GetDeleteCommand();

            log.Info("Filling Data into Adapter...");
            int modified = 0;
            int added = 0;
            foreach (DataRow dr in pca.chatDataSetG.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                if (dr.RowState == DataRowState.Modified)
                {
                    modified++;
                }
                if (dr.RowState == DataRowState.Added)
                {
                    added++;
                }
            }
            //This is where the modified count reverts
            da.Fill(pca.chatDataSetG, "Chat");
            modified = 0;
            added = 0;
            foreach (DataRow dr in pca.chatDataSetG.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                if (dr.RowState == DataRowState.Modified)
                {
                    modified ++;
                }
                if (dr.RowState == DataRowState.Added)
                {
                    added++;
                }
            }
            conn.Open();
            log.Info("Calling Update to DB...");
            int rowseffected = da.Update(pca.chatDataSetG, "Chat");
            log.Info("Update Complete - " + rowseffected + " rows effected........");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Error Updating Db with chat Data", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

    }
```

The counts are right before the fill, but after - the added count remains the same - good, but the modified count goes to 0 - bad :( . I have tried all shapes to try and see what is going on here - but honestly -  am stumped. Any help would be very, very, very much appreciated. The rows in the Db are not reflecting new values.

Peter

Comment: Where are you updating the database? Side-note: You don't need to count the changes manually, you can use [`DataTable.GetChanges(rowState)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dxfaha8.aspx). But the [`RowState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowstate.aspx) gets `Unchanged` anyway as soon as you call `DataSet.AcceptChanges` or `DataAdapter.Update(DataSet)` (you can replace DataSet with DataTable).

Comment: I am updating Db just after this:-
conn.Open();
                 log.Info("Calling Update to DB...");
                int rowseffected = da.Update(pca.chatDataSetG, "Chat");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do re-fill your DataSet/Tables at this line of code

```
//This is where the modified count reverts
da.Fill(pca.chatDataSetG, "Chat");
```

Within MSDN DataAdapter fill I think there is an explanation for the behaviour described

> You can use the Fill method **multiple times** on the same DataTable. If a
>   **primary key exists, incoming rows are merged with matching rows** that
>   already exist. **If no primary key exists, incoming rows are appended to
>   the DataTable**.

IMO modified rows got merged with the origianl owns from the db and therefore loose its rowState, wheras inserted items got appended as described.

Comment: That makes sense, so it is using the Db as primary source and is overwriting my modifies with the Db values - meaning my rowseffected is only ever equal to the number of rows that were appended as added. Would you be able to point me in the direction of a possible solution to this - I have tried writing my own update command replacement from the CB one - with the data currency issues - but if the rows are not showing as modified before I even call Update - then this doesnt matter as they wont be in scope for update anyway. Still not sure what angle to take to get these row updates going.

Comment: I'll try.. But before pls explain why you do call da.Fill (..) once again - I don't get it?!

Comment: I have misunderstood some basics around the da.Fill method. I have only pulled data - this is first time pushing and I had just popped it in there - understand where I have gone wrong now - Many Thanks. Now onwards to see why I am getting currency violations :)

Comment: Found that out as well in case anyone else gets it - my select * returned 2 calculated columns - did a fuller select ignoring these and it works fine. Read excellent wean off commandbuilder article which helped a lot - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971491.aspx